# Find variable ID's in a string with random text

Tags: java, string, search, steam

I have something like the following as a String: http://pastebin.com/8QxSC8zJ

What I actually need are the SteamIDs, e.g. "STEAM_0:1:49093894". The part "STEAM_0" is always identical, but the two numbers after that are variable. What would be the best way to retrieve these ID's as a String array?

**Update:** I looked up regular expressions like Jim Garrison suggested and came up with the following:

```
String out = //see pastebin
String[] substrings = out.split("\\s+"); //splits at whitespace

for(String a : substrings) {
    if(a.matches("STEAM_0.*")) {
        System.out.println(a);
        //add to string array/list/whatever
    }
}
```

This does indeed print all SteamID's (and I could add them to a String-Array), but how would I do this if there would be no whitespaces in the String?

Comment: Just split on *colon (:)*.

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`?  This type of question smells like "Please do my work for me".

Comment: Be aware that `STEAM_1` is a valid SteamID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want String array you have to know the length, so as to initialize the array. Let's say it is 3. You can do :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Str = new String("STEAM_0:1:49093894");
        String[] array= new String[2];

            array[0]=Str.substring(8,9) ;
            array[1]=Str.substring(9);
            }
    }
```